# How to convert a lightning table into excel file in Salesforce?

Tags: javascript, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning, aura-framework

I have a table which include a image in one column. I want to download table in Excel format with image data. Is there any way tot achieve this. My table looks like this
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am downloading this table into excel format but image is not coming in my excel file.

After opening my excel file looks like this:

[image]

I am using VF to convert my table data into excel. for ex:

```
contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think images can be exported like this. I believe that the export from Salesforce to Excel will create a CSV table as a middle step and images are not really supported.

Would it be an option to get the link to these pictures and only export the links?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve the following scenario using some workaround.  here. For that I have created a public salesforce site and in my VF file controller I have replaced my RichText Image RTA server url with my public site url and finally I have used apex Image tag to do further processing. You can see my example here.
[http://www.saleforceguy.com/wp/2022/09/11/how-to-download-rich-text-area-image-from-salesforce-to-excel-file/](https://I%20was%20able%20to%20achieve%20the%20following%20scenario%20using%20some%20workaround.%20%20here%20http://www.saleforceguy.com/wp/2022/09/11/how-to-download-rich-text-area-image-from-salesforce-to-excel-file/)